# Trying to change the color of a label through an array using Swift3

Tags: arrays, swift3, uicolor

I am working on a quiz app and I am displaying label and a couple buttons on the screen.I have an array which holds the Questions and answers to the label and buttons. The user is presented with the word of a color and the user should click the button corresponding to the word of that color.But I can't find a way to change the color of the label each time the question is changed within the array.

This is my Coding:

```
Colors = [Color (Color: (UIColor.red("Red")), Answers: ["Red","Blue","Yellow","Green"], Answer: 0 ),
                  Color(Color: "Blue", Answers: ["Red","Blue","Yellow","Green"], Answer: 1 ),
                  Color(Color: "Green", Answers: ["Red","Blue","Yellow","Green"], Answer: 3 ),
                  Color(Color: "Yellow", Answers: ["Red","Blue","Yellow","Green"], Answer: 2 )]
```

UIColor.red("Red") is wrong according to swift language

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to change the type of color property to `UIColor` from `String` then you all set to go.

```
Colors = [Color(Color: UIColor.red, Answers: ["Red","Blue","Yellow","Green"], Answer: 0 ),
              Color(Color: UIColor.blue, Answers: ["Red","Blue","Yellow","Green"], Answer: 1 ),
              Color(Color: UIColor.green, Answers: ["Red","Blue","Yellow","Green"], Answer: 3 ),
              Color(Color: UIColor.yellow, Answers: ["Red","Blue","Yellow","Green"], Answer: 2 )]
```

Comment: No I just had to add an if statement referring to the array. It would give me a string error for adding the statement in the array>

Comment: @Kique Don't get your comment, Can you please explain bit more